# Filter two List[List] given a filter List[List] keeping list in order

Tags: python, numpy

So I have two List[List] X,Y that I need to filter given a List[List] Z. The values in Y correspond to the scores of elements in X. I need to check if values of X belong to the filter in Z and keep the scores in Y corresponding to those values.

I will illustrate with an example and my current solution.

```py
# Base matrixes

X = [[2,1,3,4],
     [1,3,2,4],
     [1,2,3,4]]

Y = [[0.2,0.1,0.9,1.0],
     [0.3,0.2,0.4,0.2],
     [0.8,0.6,0.5,0.2]]

Z = [[1,2,3,4],
     [2,3],
     [1]]

# Expected results

new_x = [[2,1,3,4],
         [3,2],
         [1]]

new_y = [[0.2,0.1,0.9,1.0],
         [0.2,0.4],
         [0.8]]


# Current solution
def find_idx(a,b):
    r = []
    for idx, sub_a in enumerate(a):
        if sub_a in b:
            r+=[idx]
    return r

def filter(X, Y, Z):
    X = np.asarray(X)
    Y = np.asarray(Y)
    Z = np.asarray(Z)
    
    assert len(X)==len(Y)==len(Z)    
    r_x = []
    r_y = []
    for idx, sub_filter in enumerate(Z):
        x = find_idx(X[idx], Z[idx])
        r_x.append(X[idx][x].tolist())
        r_y.append(Y[idx][x].tolist())
    return r_x, r_y
        

r_x, r_y = filter(X,Y,Z)
```

I figured out I could easily do this with a collection of list comprehensions, but performance is important for this function.

Is there any way to speed up the part where i find the indexes of values of X that are in Z to later filter X,Y by them?

Comment: This is not a good use case for numpy (ragged array as output). Please provide your current working code.

Comment: @mozway just updated the comment with my current solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more efficient way to do that when the input matrices are big:

```
X = np.array([
    [2, 1, 3, 4],
    [1, 3, 2, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
])

Y = np.array([
    [0.2, 0.1, 0.9, 1.0],
    [0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2],
    [0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.2],
])

Z = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [2, 3],
     [1],
     ]

mask = np.zeros(X.shape)

new_x = []
new_y = []
for i, z_row in enumerate(Z):
    mask = np.isin(X[i], z_row)
    new_x.append(X[i][mask].tolist())
    new_y.append(Y[i][mask].tolist())
```

It was roughly 10x faster than the list comprehension when I tested it with 5000x5000 matrices. This is because the list comprehension has to loop over all elements of the list `z` when using the `in` operator.

Comment: Makes sense! I was looking exactly for something like this with mask. Speeding up checking what values belong to the filter Z with numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Using a nested list comprehension:

```
x_new = [[x[i-1] for i in z] for x,z in zip(X, Z)]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 1, 3, 4],
 [3, 2],
 [1]]
```

Comment: how would you go about new_y? Would be good to have the indexes of the values taken to create new_x and slice Y by them.

Comment: You can do exactly the same. I don't think there is a benefit in trying to handle X and Y in parallel. Wrap everything in a function to be able to do `new_X = f(X, Z)` and `new_Y = f(Y, Z)`

Comment: but we will be looping twice then. The indexes of the results in X are guaranteed to be the indixes for Y as well so we can save double time just with that.

Comment: Are you sure it will double the time? I don't think so, the looping time is just not use in the same place ;)

Comment: well if you keep the indexes when you loop over X then you know for sure you wont have to loop over Y as then you will slice and that is (1)

Answer (score 1):

```py
new_x = []
new_y = []
zipped_xy = [list(zip(*el)) for el in zip(X, Y)]


for idx, v in enumerate(Z):
    temp_x = []
    temp_y = []
    for x, y in zipped_xy[idx]:
        if x in v:
            temp_x.append(x)
            temp_y.append(y)
    new_x.append(temp_x)
    new_y.append(temp_y)
print(new_x)
print(new_y)
# [[2, 1, 3, 4], [3, 2], [1]]
# [[0.2, 0.1, 0.9, 1.0], [0.2, 0.4], [0.8]]
```